# Get and remove all current entries from a ConcurrentMap

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` accumulating some changes which should be periodically sent somewhere (for a sort of replication). Concerning the changes, only the most recent value for any key matters.

So I need to get and remove some snapshot. The snapshot needn't be atomic, it's enough when each its entry reflects the state of the original map at some instant during the operation.

The important part is that only the entries which are present and up to date in the result may be removed from the original map. I guess, the following should do:

```
<K, V> ConcurrentMap<K, V> getAndRemoveAll(ConcurrentMap<K, V> map) {
    ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(map);    
    result.forEach((resultKey, resultValue) -> 
    map.computeIfPresent(resultKey,
        (k, mapValue) -> mapValue==resultValue ? null : mapValue)); 
    return result;
}
```

Is this really correct? Is it possible in a single iteration?

Comment: @JoeC it would if the code was working correctly, but I am pretty sure it is not. OP is comparing Objects with `==`, which in general will not work correctly.

Comment: @JoeC The four lines are nothing but a description of what it should do, not really something to be reviewed.

Comment: @Turing85 Using `==` is probably fine here, as when a value gets replaced by another one which is not the same but `equals`, then a value is needlessly allowed to stay in the map. It's correct in the sense that it's not (exactly) the value present in the result, which means that the map has changed after the snapshot was taken.

Comment: Is using a simple lock something possible? Is `ConcurrentHashMap` the right implementation for what you want to do?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I can't tell. The copying may get expensive and I wouldn't like to block writers. OTOH, I could probably just switch the map for an empty one. So locking may be the right solution for my use case. However, I'm still curious what's the answer to the question as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`remove(Object key, Object value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#remove-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-), which will only remove the entry *if the value is up-to-date*, and the operation is atomic.

**So this is what I suggest:**

```
<K, V> Map<K, V> getAndRemoveAll(ConcurrentMap<K, V> map) {
  return map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> map.remove(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```